# Interline in lists (items, item parapgraphs)

Tags: support, design, markdown

Let's take this question as an example: [How to save a context into an expression?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/161948/5478)

[image]

The distance between the second item and its paragraph is larger than the distance between the next or the previous item.

It is at least confusing but I find it also ugly. Even more in the mobile app.

I have not found related topics here or in meta.se so let's start a discussion here and escalate it if needed.

The question is, is this intended?

If so, what is the way to go when writing bullet items with paragraphs? In given example item is marked by `"- "` and a paragraph by `" "`.

If not, is it a side effect of a more important feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Update

[m_golberg points out](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2258/interline-in-lists-items-item-parapgraphs/2259?noredirect=1#comment9772_2259) that there's another way to get in a `<br/>`, namely by using two spaces before the newline, i.e. `\n`.

So we can use this:

```
- `DumpSave` is not portable enough

- `Save` saves `$Context` and `$ContextPath` (everything what is not protected) together with all definitions so loading it will affect environment.  
I can load it within additional `Begin/EndPackage` but I don't like it.

- I don't know how to use ``Language` `` functions to do this.
```

to get the same effect:

- `DumpSave` is not portable enough
- `Save` saves `$Context` and `$ContextPath` (everything what is not protected) together with all definitions so loading it will affect environment.
  I can load it within additional `Begin/EndPackage` but I don't like it.
- I don't know how to use `` Language` `` functions to do this.

#### Original

Markdown only supports newlines as `<p>` (which causes the whitespace you see). You'll have to fall back to HTML for this.

You can get a nicer wrapping using an explicit `<br/>`.

E.g.:

```
- `DumpSave` is not portable enough

- `Save` saves `$Context` and `$ContextPath` (everything what is not protected) together with all definitions so loading it will affect environment. <br/> I can load it within additional `Begin/EndPackage` but I don't like it.

- I don't know how to use ``Language` `` functions to do this.
```

displays as:

- `DumpSave` is not portable enough
- `Save` saves `$Context` and `$ContextPath` (everything what is not protected) together with all definitions so loading it will affect environment. 
   I can load it within additional `Begin/EndPackage` but I don't like it.  asd
- I don't know how to use `` Language` `` functions to do this.

Comment: Newline before `<br/>` keeps it readable for author too. It needs two consecutive newlines to start a paragraph.

Comment: You don't need `<br/>` to force a line break; putting two spaces before a line break is is translated to `<br/>` and is easier to type.

Comment: @m_goldberg that's it, it seems they need to be placed in the previous line, I'm not surprised I missed that.